# Warning message upon opening VS2015. "There was a ... loading your Microsoft Azure settings..."

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My VS 2015 was installed via some image at my new company. Every time I open it, I get the below error message:

[image]

"There was a problem loading your Microsoft Azure settings. Please try importing your subscription settings again."

Has anyone had experience with resolving this? I don't need Azure at all, is this some plugin that I can disable?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of this message on my company computer by signing into a Microsoft account then signing back out. The account I used was in no way connected to my company. Probably not the most correct answer, but it did the job

File -> Account Settings -- Sign In, Sign Out

Comment: The account I'm using is my company's account. Thanks though!